# TV show about people being saved just before they are supposed to die

Tags: story-identification, tv, teleportation

In the first (or maybe an early) episode, a man (senator?) is about to die in a plane crash, but at the last moment, someone teleports in and creates a shield bubble to save him.

It has something to do with him having to die at a later date?(By assassination?) Which he obviously didn't.

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667879/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt?

Comment: @Bazzaman - Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year (or range of years) did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: I would say 2010,give or take a few years. It was most likely cancelled after 1 season.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be [S01E09 of *Travelers*](https://metawitches.com/2017/01/04/travelers-season-1-episode-9-bishop-recap/):

> [Maclaren] has a flight to catch that afternoon, where he’ll be seated
> next to his target, Congressman Bishop.

and

> The plane runs into trouble, as expected. There’s heavy turbulence and
> lithium batteries catch fire in the cargo hold. The black case opens
> at nearly the last moment. Philip explains that it’s a two person
> stasis field designed to protect McLaren and Bishop from the crash,
> then throw them clear on the ground.

and

> The plane crashes in a spectacular show of special effects. Bishop and
> Kathryn survive, but Bishop is immediately taken over by a traveler,

Which means that the Travelers have a future use for him.

Comment: Thanks, didn't click that it was the travelers.

Comment: @Bazzaman - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].